# Run program from graphical environment

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher

I have installed LogMx GUI software in my Ubuntu `/opt/` directory. Installation was simple - just unzip folder to `/opt/` directory. I can run it fine with script `logmx.sh` from terminal window. But how to make it appear Unity or any other graphic environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the application appear in your Unity menu by creating a desktop launcher of the application.

It will appear if you place this launcher either in either of these two folders:

Folder fo all uesrs:

```
/usr/share/applications
```

or

Local Folder for just your login:

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

**Creating the Launcher**

While there are many details and option you can place in your launcher, this is the basics:

Create a file with the extension `.desktop`.   Place this information.

`LogMx.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=[Full path of your icon]
Name[en_US]=LogMx GUI
Exec=/opt/logmx.sh
Comment[en_US]=My LogMx GUI installation
Name=LogMx GUI
Comment=My LogMx GUI installation
Icon=[Full pathname of your icon]
Categories=GUI;software
```

You can find details of creating `Desktop Launcher` files at:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles